# Single Player Only achievements

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I have recently acquired Lego Harry Potter 1-4 and was browsing the achievements when I noticed that a lot of them say Single Player Only ([Xbox Achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/achievements/))

Searching the web for what this means seems to produce a multitude of answers, many contradicting one another, common responses being:

- The game (or steps towards an achievement) must be played entirely alone
- The main player (the one with the xbox live account) will be the only one to get the achievement, but two people can play
- The main player *must be the one to do* the steps toward an achievement, but two can play
- Both players get the achievement

The most common response is probably point 2, but then some confusion arises from what a "main player" is and a secondary.

My situation: I own an Xbox live account, and I would like the achievements. My gf has created an account on my xbox (an "offline" account I believe it is called) but has no interest in achievements (don't even know if it can even earn them?). Ideally, I would like to only play through the game once, earning the achievements (for my account) as we play together. What steps do I need to take to accomplish this? If we both log into our profiles, will I void any chance? Alternatively, if only *I* log in, and then my gf presses 'start' once in game, is this allowed?

I've tried to get an official response from Lego about the matter but as yet no response.

Comment: The more likely answer actually is, you must be playing by yourself to achieve these achievments, which means a second ( human ) player cannot control the other character.  The best way is to attempt the simplest one and see what the result is.

Comment: If you are looking for a definitive answer to which achievement is singleplayer only and which is not, try trueachievements.com. The achievement categories for each achievement have to go through strict selection process.

Comment: This generally means you have to play it alone on a single player account, but whether these are bugs, a miss understanding or what these can be got when playing coop as well. It is normally to separate it the single player achievements from the multiplayer achievements. So normally it should be coop and multiplayer (Team Deathmatch etc) would normally say `(Multiplayer)` and the single player achievements would have `(Single Player)` on them. but like i say bug or not you can seem to get single player ones in coop sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My son and daughter played this, both logged into their Xbox accounts.  Whoever's game it was (i.e. selected at the start screen, usually by player one) was the one that got the achievements.  The other person did not get them.

So, the answer is a slight modification of #2 above. Only one player gets the achievement, but it is the player whos saved game you are playing.  If the other player wanted the achievement as well (my daughter didn't care), then they would have to play again with a different save game chosen.

Comment: That's very interesting. I had no idea that a saved game through one profile was not visible to other profiles on the xbox, although it does make sense when I think about it. It also does make it a bit more obvious who would get the achievement. I should hopefully be earning the lessons complete achievement soon so I will report back whether or not I receive it after playing entirely in co-op mode. Slight side, what happens if you create a save game when two controllers are active? Does it belong to whoever is controller number 1?

Comment: @Chris, my experience with the save games is it belongs to whoever presses start and chooses the save location.  I can't verify that right now (at work), but it should be easy enough to test out.

Comment: Good morning APrough. Well last night I earned this achievement 'Complete All Story Lessons (Single Player Only)' whilst playing in co-op mode with my gf, so on that basis it certainly seems to back up your answer. I can't remember if she logged into her Xbox profile when we did this (I was still player one) but advice for others, I would say that: yes you can earn achievements for at least one account, but to be safe I would have player 2 join once the game has loaded (pressing start on the controller) as I think we did this most. PS. I never got an official response back.